# Spaces in a folder name

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, folders

I have a foldername with a space between the name: `/Volumes/Img/Horos Data/DATABASE/`

I need to put it in a variable to use in a script.

In terminal I can use `\` to use the folder: `cd /Volumes/Dados/Horos\ Data/DATABASE/`, but it doesn't work when I put in a variable like:

```
DESTINY=/Volumes/Dados/Horos\ Data/DATABASE.noindex/
ls $DESTINY
```

How can I put it in a variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables or arguments on the right side of a command are subject to word spliting by the shell unless quoted. You can try the following demonstration.

```
touch foo\ bar\ baz
#
ls foo\ bar\ baz
foo bar baz
# or
ls "foo bar baz"
foo bar baz
#
var=foo\ bar\ baz
ls $var
ls: bar: No such file or directory
ls: baz: No such file or directory
ls: foo: No such file or directory
#
ls "$var"
foo bar baz
```

Answer (score 4):

Quotes can be used to escape spaces when assigning to a variable.

```
var="abc def ghi"
```

Comment: It is not working with Quotes!
I´ve tried  with double and single quotes  and return a error.
DESTINY=/Volumes/Dados/Horos Data/DATABASE/
error= link_stat "/Volumes/Dados/Horos" failed: No such file or directory (2)

Comment: ... except it's when you *use* the variable via something like `blah $var` that the POSIX word split bites you